# Firebase security rules check multiple references

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am developing an application in which I need a set of users (employees) belonging to a group (store) to only be able to read from the "Customers" table if these customers have an order placed by an employee in the same store.
This is my structure thus far (top level are collections):

```
Users: [
 {id: 1, name: "John", store: "a"},
 {id: 2, name: "Jane", store: "a"},
 {id: 3, name: "Charles", store: "b"},
],
Stores: [
 {id: "a", name: "Store A"},
 {id: "b", name: "Store B"},
],
Customers: [
 {id: "1", name: "Customer 1", ...data},
 {id: "2", name: "Customer 2", ...data}
],
Orders: [
 {id: "001", customer: "/Customers/1", employee: "/Users/1"},
 {id: "002", customer: "/Customers/2", employee: "/Users/3"}
]
```

In this example, John and Jane should be able to see the **Customer 1** but not the Customer 2, and Charles should be able to see the **Customer 2** but not the Customer 1.

I tried to make a function to do this, like so:

```
function canSeeCustomers() {
    if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.store == ?
}
```

But I don't know how to check the *store* field against the *Orders* collection.

Is there any way to do this? Or would I be better refactoring the DB structure to make *Users* a subdocument of *Stores*?

Answer (score 0):

Add stores to your customers data too. `stores: {a: true}`.
So you could do

```
allow read: if resource.data.stores[get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.store];
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer (I was on vacation). Your answer didn't work out, but your idea of saving the stores to the document data allowed me to come up with the answer: `allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.store in resource.data.stores;`. Thank you tho :)